# Multiple Bootstrap datepickers in one page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have a little problem with Boostrap datepickers.

```
$('#date1,#date2,#date3,#date4,#date5,#date6').datetimepicker({
      language:  'es',
      weekStart: 1,
      todayBtn:  1,
      autoclose: 1,
      todayHighlight: 1,
      startView: 2,
      minView: 2,
      forceParse: 0
});
```

The problem is that from date2 to date6 are created with jQuery when the users clicks a buttom and the datetimepicker is not working, only the date1.How can I solve this? Thanks

Comment: perhaps use `{ language:  'es',
      weekStart: 1,
      todayBtn:  true,
      autoclose: true,
      todayHighlight: true,
      startView: 2,
      minViewMode: 2,
      forceParse: false}`   Note that it would be better to add a class and then select on that rather than multiple ID's (make maintenance easier)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding as an answer to clarify the class comment.  Use a class on your newly added elements, then create the datepicker by attaching to the body or document such as:

```
<div class='input-group date datepicker-me-class' id='date2'>
  <input type='text' class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Now attach to the document:

```
$(document).on('focus', ".datepicker-me-class", function() {
  $(this).datepicker({
    language: 'es',
    weekStart: 1,
    todayBtn: true,
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    startView: 2,
    minViewMode: 2,
    forceParse: false
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! That solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

DEMO: It is seems it is working, may be the option you have added like

```
 language:  'es',
  weekStart: 1,
  todayBtn:  1,
  autoclose: 1,
  todayHighlight: 1,
  startView: 2,
  minView: 2,
  forceParse: 0
```

are creating problems, please check the datetimepicker version that you are using if these option are available or not.

```js
$('#datetimepicker1,#datetimepicker2,#datetimepicker3,#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>

<div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" /> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker2">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" /> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" /> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" /> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
            </div>
```

Comment: The problem is that datetimepicker1 is the only one present in the code, the others are created dynamically with jQuery, and I believe that's the problem